# How to write a database "Save" method for a self-tracked class?

Tags: c#

In order to ask the question let me 
write a class which contain my question.

```
class Student{

public int StudentId;
public string Name;
public int Age;
public string Address;


public void Save(){
   if (StudentId == 0){
   //// run the insert query here
/*
Insert into Student(Studentid,Name,Age,Address)values(...);
} else {
/// run the update query...
/*Update Student Set Address = @address , Age = @age , Name = @name
where StudentId = @stdid;*/
}
}
```

Now in order to use that class I will write the following code.

```
Student Std = new Student{StudentId = 1, Name="xyz", Address = "Home"};

Std.Save(); //// this will insert the value in the database
```

Now later on.

```
Student std1 = new Student();

std1.Studentid = 1;
std1.Age= 10;
std1.Save();
```

Now calling save this time will over write the Address with Null or empty string.

I seek advise on possible solutions to this problem.

There is a possibility that consumer wants to change the address with empty string.

Looking forward to replies.

Regards

K

}

Comment: This form of database access is sometimes referred to as "self-tracking" because the objects themselves "track" the DB .. (The amount of tracking they do can vary a good bit.)

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is instantiating a *new* `Student` object, and simply assigning new values to it. Since you never assign an address, it will be `null`.

Your insert/update logic is flawed, because it *assumes* that having a `0` for an ID means that the values have already been persisted (which may or may not be the case - your class design does allow for creation of a `Student` that is not persisted and give it any old ID). The result is that you are saving the values to the database, including the `null` address.

Your logic should be:

- If student ID is not 0:

  - Start a transaction
  - Get student details from DB
  - Update student object with new details
  - Save
  - Commit the transaction

You should also restructure your `Student` class so the `Id` can't be simply written to (possibly just in the constructor) and have a way to load a `Student` from your database.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. But how to know later on user has changed the Address from some value to empty string or may be user has not provided anything.

Comment: @user651367 - Well, if you want to copy all the values, copy all the values. I would say there are flaws in your design - if you load the values from the database, display them and then when the user submits them you compare them all, you will be able to tell. Not sure why you are doing all this manual database work instead of using an ORM, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should setup your structure differently.

Right now you are creating a new `Student` object fill it with (only) the changed data, and trying to update it by `Studentid`.

I think you should also create a (static) method like `GetStudentById(int id)`. Let this return the student from the database with all properties filled, make your changes and write it back with the `Save()`. Now the values won't be empty or reset.

Comment: Hiya thanks for your reply. Question is how to know that user has provided Age not the address and depending upon that perform an update.

Comment: If you do it like this, you don't have to worry about it. You get all the current values for your student from the database, update the values you like and write back all the current values in memory back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of managing default values in your code, that can *vary* during a time, can be a lot, it's easier to manage default value setup on `DB` side. Just set the field of corresponding `DB` field *default value* to the value you need and stop carrying about it in your code. Naturally if you *have* access to DB structure and allowed to change it.

If you **don't want** reset the valu in a new object (it's not very clear from your post), just use a (say) `Clone(..)` method of your `Student` type, and after change only fields that very.

Example:

```
Student std= new Student{StudentId = 1, Name="xyz", Address = "Home"};
Std.Save();

//after 

Student std1 = std.Clone(); //after clone you have Adrress field too in std1    
std1.Studentid = 1;
std1.Age= 10;
std1.Save();
```

Comment: but mate my question is how to know the consumer of that class has used which field and depending upon the usage update the record. Clone will provide a copy of the object separately but that is not what I want to achieve. My prime question is how to know whether user has set the Address field or not. Depending upon that perform a save.

Comment: @user651367: at this point you can simply get `Student` object from DB, and check the fields of interest against *default value*. For example: you get `Student st` from DB and see that `st.Address == null` (which, say, a *default value* in your case). So you figure out that none yet setup `Address` property on that object, so in DB too.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic method you can use for it... You'll simply have to check for `null` and decide whether to overwrite or not at some point.

There are ORM frameworks you can use like NHibernate or Entity Framework that will do the plumbing like this automatically if you're interested.

Comment: What do you think of creating maintaining a list of all the properties used by the consumer and than depending upon that constructing a sql statement on the fly ?

Comment: well, that will make you create the property twice, and a whole lot of validation code. It can be easily done via reflection. If you have a lot of this type of objects (Student, Lesson, Teacher, Course .etc.) using an ORM framework like Entity Framework will save you a LOT of code and a crazy amount of debugging in the future.